# How to use the try function on multiple lines of text in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Hi I am scraping text of a website each day which is in the form of a dataframe in python and i have a line of code which looks for the index number of the first time `Day n` appears:

```
Scrape example 1:
Text
acb
xyz
Day 1
hij
mno

Scrape example 2
Text
acb
xyz
Day 4
hij
mno
```

my code to do this is:

```
 startrow = df.index[df['Text'].str.startswith(('Day 1', 'Day 1:'))].item()
```

but I run into issues (`value error`) when the first instance is Day 2+ (like the scrape example 2).

Should I be using the `try` function to search for `Day 1`, and then if not `Day 2`, `Day 3` etc or is there a better way to do it? The max would be `Day 12`. And if so can you put `try` inside of another `try` or is there more efficient ways to do this?

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks

Comment: If I understand this correctly, all you need to do is back off from requiring a particular number.  Use `startswith("Day ")`, and you should get the lines you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
from natsort import index_natsorted
s=df.loc[df['Text'].str.startswith(('Day ')),'Text']
s.index[np.array(index_natsorted(s))==0]
Out[41]: Int64Index([2], dtype='int64')
```

Input dataframe

```
df
Out[42]: 
    Text
0  Day 4
1    xyz
2  Day 1
3    hij
4    mno
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are calling `.item()` even though you don't know if the `Day 1` is present in the current scrape dataframe. Instead you could iterate over range of days (if you know that the max will be 12), something like:

```
for i in range(1, 13):
    day_i_rows = df[df['Text'].str.startswith(f'Day {i}')]
    if len(day_i_rows) > 0:
        start_day_i_index = day_i_rows.index.item()
```

Comment: thanks ill give that a go. and then how would i attribute that back to the `startrow` variable?